# Select se não existir em outra tabela, porém se não existir registro em 24h

Tags: mysql

**Tenho duas tabelas:**

*links*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*works*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Preciso retornar os valores da tabela links, mas antes preciso ver se ela existe na tabela works, e se existir ela tem que ter sido inserido a mais de 24h, caso contrario esse registro não poderá ser retornado na consulta.**

***Consultar e retornar só o que não tenho na tabela works é facil, faço assim:***

```
SELECT *
FROM links l
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM works w
    WHERE w.linkId = l.linkId
)
```

**Mas preciso retornar só os registros inseridos a mais de 24h**

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar a verificação da `datahora` no seu `sub-select` utilizando a função `DATE_SUB`:

```
SELECT *
FROM links l
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM works w
    WHERE w.linkId = l.linkId
    AND w.datahora <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
)
```

Veja mais sobre `DATE_SUB` [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp).